# writing binary file in C

Tags: c

I realize this question has been asked a ton, and I've searched through (most) of the articles, but I just can't seem to write a file in binary. I can open the file and write in human-readable format, but what I want is non-human-readable data written to the file (like hex). I'm aware of the "xxd" command on Linux, but I'm wondering how I can mimic that using C. The relevant code I have so far is as follows (the opening of the file followed by the writing of the file:

```
extern FILE* file;
static char file_buffer[16384];
file = fopen("audit_log", "wb");

if ( !file )
{
    printf("failed to open file");
    exit(1);
}


if ( !fwrite( &file_buffer, 1, sizeof(file_buffer), file ) )
    printf("fwrite failed\n");

fclose(file)
```

I've done my research and my testing and used all different kinds of modes for fopen() using the "b" parameter, paired with fwrite(), but none of these methods have aided me in writing a binary file to C. Am I missing something trivial? I can't seem to figure out why I can't write a simple file in binary. Thanks!

Comment: `fclose(file);`, then `fwrite` on the now-defunct `FILE* file` is not a good plan. Post minimal, *real*, and *complete* code that exhibits your problem. If the code in your question can't be cut/paste to a text file, compiled, linked, and run to reproduce your symptoms, it isn't enough.

Comment: ... and what does `loop()` do ?

Comment: what do you mean by 'writing binary'?. As far as C is concerned that simply means "dont add any extra line termination characters", I suspect that you are expecting the data to be transformed somehow.Sounds like you actually want a hex dump of a file

Comment: Basically you are always writing binary in unix.  Some other environments make a distinction between text and binary files based on the fact that MS-DOS legacy line-ends are two characters, and plays games to make a linefeed into a carriage_return+linefeed..  Linux isn't one of them

Comment: I pasted code from a couple different modules, which is why it originally showed me doing fclose() then an fwrite(). I've corrected that now. loop() runs a subroutine, and was included in between, which isn't important (and I'll probably remove now). Yes, I'm trying to get C to write a hex dump; perhaps I wasn't using the right terminology.

Comment: `if (!fwrite(...))` is not the complete detection of `fwrite()` failure.

Comment: "I've corrected that now." is not good SO etiquette.  It makes your post a moving target and negates the first comments.  Suggest rolling back to before your "fix".

Comment: I will point out that `xxd` and `hexdump` are utilities that take files that may not be human readable, and expresses them into a hexadecimal representation that can be interpreted.  That's  the opposite of writing a binary file.  Perhaps you're looking for the `%x` format of `printf`?

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do? `file_buffer` is an uninitialized array, and writing it to a file will just write junk memory to it.  You say you want to produce a binary file, what do you want in it? If by binary, you mean executable, then the file you are producing must either be interpreted by another program or compiled down to machine code.  A bmp image is a binary file that follows a specific format, give us an example of how you plan to use this/what you want to achieve and we may be able to help.

Comment: @chux Fair enough, but data is being written to the file, just not the hex dump (which is where I'm probably doing something wrong).

Comment: Justin, I want to reiterate here that you may be using the wrong vocabulary.  While hex dumps are often used as a tool for dealing with binary files, they are not the binary file being discussed themselves.  Its just a way to put binary bits into a format that can be read as numbers.  If you want to make hex dumps, you are actually going to be making a text file of hexadecimal digits for output

Comment: @infixed I apologize if I'm using the wrong terminology. What I want is something along the lines of the "xxd" command on Linux, which I believe is a hex dump. I have a bash script which does this, but I was just wondering if there's an easy way of doing this using C.

Comment: try a line `printf("Dump = %02x %02x %02x %02x\n", 1, 2, 3, 15);` and see if that gets you started in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

One problem that you have is that you are not actually putting any data in your file_buffer, so what you would be writing to your file is random garbage found in memory.

The real problem that you have is that:

```
if ( !fwrite( &file_buffer, 1, sizeof(file_buffer), file ) )
```

should be:

```
if ( !fwrite( file_buffer, 1, sizeof(file_buffer), file ) )
```

You are passing in a pointer to a pointer, not the simple pointer to char fwrite was expecting.

Comment: My apologies for not including every bit of my code. I actually do populate file_buffer, I just don't show it here because that part is working correctly (and most likely isn't relevant to the problem I have at hand). I also made the correction you suggested, but the output file was the same.

Comment: Try using perror () then to get a human readable error message from the fwrite failure.

Answer (score 1):

A file contents are series of bytes. Now, it is the application which is trying to read a file that interprets what type of file it is depending on the values of those bytes.

For example if your file contains bytes whose values are all within printable ASCII values, then applications will treat that file as an ASCII file.

You can write any value to a byte in file. For example the program below:

```
/* main: write a new filej */
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char c;
    FILE *fp;

    /* open a file to write */
    fp = fopen("test_file", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
             printf("Open Error\n");
             return 1;
    }

    /* write some data to file  */
    for (c=0; c < 200; c++)
            fputc(c, fp);

    /* close file */
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

will write 200 bytes to `test_file`. Out of those 200 bytes are some characters which are human readable, and some are non-human-readable, as seen below.

```
[05:52 PM] $ wc test_file 
1   1 200 test_file
[05:52 PM] $ cat test_file 
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~����������������������������������������������������������������������[05:52 PM] $
```

So, you can write anything into a file. It is then the applicaton which reads the file interpret it of some type. For example, lets use `file` application used coomnly in linux:

```
[05:55 PM] $ file test_file 
test_file: Targa image data - RGBA (1027-1541) 3340 x 3854 x 16 +2312 +2826 - 1-bit alpha - right
[05:55 PM]
```

`file` utility is treating this file as some image data file.